# How to calculate result of overlaying two color integers with alpha channels on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, colors

I have two colors with alpha channels represented as integers on Android and I need to get the result color of these colors being overlayed over each other (as if I had two semi-transparent views on each other).

I have already tried to use the variations of `ColorUtils.blendARGB` but that is not exactly what I need.

I can easily calculate something like this:

```
/**
 * Takes receiver as top color and attempts to overlay it over param color.
 * Result is basically [ColorUtils.blendARGB] but in overlay mode instead of blend mode.
 */
infix fun Int.overlay(bottomColor: Int): Int {
    val ratio = 1 - ((Color.alpha(this) / 255f) * (Color.alpha(bottomColor) / 255f))
    return ColorUtils.blendARGB(ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(this, 255), ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(bottomColor, 255), ratio)
}
```

It is however obvious that this will not work in case both colors have alpha channel as it will remove alpha completely.

How can I also keep the alpha channel of both overlaying colors?

Comment: i see a bug in your code.

Comment: @Roger Well - I do, obviously, too. I just do not know how to fix (or rewrite) it properly, otherwise I would not ask the question here in the first place :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will blend colours respecting their alphas.

```
@ColorInt infix fun @receiver:ColorInt Int.overlay(@ColorInt bottomColor: Int): Int {
    val topAlpha = Color.alpha(this)
    val bottomAlpha = Color.alpha(bottomColor)
    val alphaSum = bottomAlpha + topAlpha
    return Color.argb(
        Math.min(255, alphaSum),
        (Color.red(bottomColor) * bottomAlpha + Color.red(this) * topAlpha) / alphaSum,
        (Color.green(bottomColor) * bottomAlpha + Color.green(this) * topAlpha) / alphaSum,
        (Color.blue(bottomColor) * bottomAlpha + Color.blue(this) * topAlpha) / alphaSum
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work perfectly, thank you! 
I would just note that correct syntax for receiver annotation would be:
`@ColorInt
infix fun @receiver:ColorInt Int.overlay(@ColorInt bottomColor: Int): Int`